# undefined is not a function evaluating 0,reactnavigation.createDrawerNavigator

Tags: android, react-native, navigation-drawer

I have below code

```
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer,DrawerNavigator,createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';
    const RootStack = createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Details: DetailsScreen,
      },
      {
        intialRouteName: 'Home',
        navigationOptions: {
          headerStyle : {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle : {
            color: 'white',
          },
        },
      }
    );


    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <RootStack/>;
      }
    }
```

It is always showing error

> undefined is not a function evaluating
>   0,reactnavigation.createDrawerNavigator

I tried different solution found over net but always getting same error, looks like version issue of 'react-navigation'

**"react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.23"**

My first day on react-native so could not able to get it.

Any help, appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using `react-navigation` version 3?

Answer (score 1):

I set up my drawer navigation like this:

make a route.js file and add all of this codes on there

> notice: instead of componentName add your component Name

```
import { StackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import DrawerScreen from 'your/drawer/component/path'
import componentName from 'your/component/path/componentName'

const Navigator = StackNavigator({
    componentName: { screen: componentName, navigationOptions: { header:null }}},
{
   mode: 'modal',
   headerMode: 'none',
   initialRouteName: componentName

});

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({  Navigator },
  {
      contentComponent:DrawerScreen,
      drawerPosition:"left"
  });

module.exports = MyDrawerNavigator;
```

then on your app.js file import your

> MyDrawerNavigator

like this

```
import MyDrawerNavigator from 'path/to/routes.js'
```

then use it like this on app.js

```
export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
        <MyDrawerNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

that's it :)

> I use react-navigation version --> 2.5.5

hopefully, it works for you.

Comment: Could you please create a snack for me, I am writing the first  program and very difficult to re-write your code and make it run